# How can I edit my drop down list to show me the results with AJAX? (No reload)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a form that shows different (extra) fields based on the onChange selection of the following drop down list.

What I did, I get the value and if the value equals to an IF statement it displays the correct extra field for the selected category. This procedure is done with a reload of the page.

My question is how can I build it using Ajax and avoid reloading? An Ajax call on the OnChange otion maybe..
Thank you!

```
<select 
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex&gt;0) window.location.href = 'http://mypage/?something&value=+this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value" 
class="select" id="termid" name="termid">
<option value="46">CARS</option>
.
.
</select>
```

this is something I found from a tutorial

```
$(function() {
    $('#sel').change(function() {
        $("input").hide().filter("." + $(this).find("option:selected").val()).show();
    });
    $("input").focus(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeIn(1000);
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

and the css that hides everything

```
input{
    display:none;
}
span
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps to transform a new page load in an ajax call on the same page:

1. You need to make a php file that just returns the html for the extra fields (no `head`, `body`, your select, etc.)
2. You need to change your event handler. As you are using jQuery, you can remove all inline javascript and just replace it with `$('#termid').change(function() { // your ajax stuff here });`
3. The easiest ajax call in jQuery is the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method so you could use that like `$('#some_div_below_select').load('your_new_php_file.php&value=' + $(this).val());`. That puts the contents that are generated with you new php file in the element with ID `some_div_below_select`.

In the part where I put your ajax stuff, you can add the necessary checks like the `if` statement you have now.

To sum up the javascript part (I changed the way the parameter is passed):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#termid').change(function() {
    $('#some_div_below_select').load('your_new_php_file.php', { "value" : $(this).val() });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi jeroen, thank you for your info and example. I accept your answer and I will try to use it ( i am kind of new in Ajax ). I will keep you updated with any questions!

Comment: @Punkis You´re welcome! jQuery makes ajax pretty easy and the documentation is great.

Comment: I have a quick one. to avoid if statements, I would like to have my files the same name as the value. like if the user selects option 1 with value 1, the php file is value.php

Comment: @Punkis Then you need something like $("#termid option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript change event. Bind that event to the select list and make the ajax call to update the list when change is fired.

If using JQuery nice and easy and lots of documentation